# converting xinput coordinates to a square

Tags: c#, math, coordinates, xinput

i'm working on a small c# program that uses xinput to read the xbox 360 thumb stick.

i have no problem with reading the coordinates and normalizing the values so i get a float between -1 and +1 for X and Y directions.
the problem i have is that the stick itself is physically limited to a circle and in my case i would like to "stretch out" the coordinates so it becomes more of a square than a circle.

the reason is that each direction is controlling a motor and if i move the stick for example top right i would like both X and Y to become 1.
since the stick is circular this is not possible and this also makes it impossible to make both motors run at full speed.

any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a point on a circle of radius r to be mapped to a point on a square of radius r on the same ray through the origin. Toward that goal you have to compute the radius using the usual formula

```
r = sqrt(x*x+y*y)
```

and then from that the scale factor

```
f = r / max ( abs(x), abs(y) )
```

and in the end replace x by f*x and y by f*y.

One can vary this computation by noting that the factor is

```
f = sqrt ( 1 + (x*x)/(y*y) )
```

if `abs(y) > abs(x)` and

```
f = sqrt ( 1 + (y*y)/(x*x) )
```

in the opposite case. Or by noting that the largest coordinate gets replaced by r and the smaller scaled accordingly, which also does not reduce the logistics by much.

Comment: thanks, that helped.
now i just need to find out why my normalization sometimes makes x and y larger than 1.
i bet i have some other errors, time for a bit of debugging.